# How to add Subitem to a customized listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am  using a custom List view like this.How to add subitems(inbox) to the list item(from)??

```
      for (int k = 0; k < fromb.length; ++k) {
        if(k==0)
        {
             frin = fromb[k]+"\n"+inboxb[k];
        }
        else
        {
              frin = frin + "##"+fromb[k]+"\n"+inboxb[k];
        }

    }

    frin1=frin.split("##");
    lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_choice, frin1));
    //lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_choice, inboxb));
    lView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                 String s1=(String) ((TextView) view).getText();


                 for (int i=0;i<frin1.length;i++)
                 {
                     //Log.i("TextOnly2",bookmarkurlsb[i]);
                     if(frin1[i]==s1)
                     {  
                         String fromf=fromb[i];
                         String inboxf=inboxb[i];
                         Intent intent = new Intent(Inbox.this,Details.class);
                         intent.putExtra("from", fromf);
                         intent.putExtra("inbox", inboxf);
                         startActivity(intent);
                     }
                     else
                     {

                     }
                 }

                }
            });
```

Layout: R.layout.single_choice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/TextView15"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="17sp"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:paddingLeft="6dip"
   android:paddingTop="15dp"
   android:paddingBottom="15dp" 
   android:background="#444444"
   android:textColor="@color/list_color"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a baseAdapter object, which will generate the view for you.

check out this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/).

The most important part for your question is getView function under the baseAdapter class.